Emails sent via Journey don't show up in the Marketing Cloud Calendar?
In this page of the documentation, it says
This list displays searchable items stored in your Calendar.

All completed email sends
User-initiated
Programs
Automation Studio
API

Seeing Automation Studio in the options I was under the impression that Journey Builder sends would show up in the calendar as well. Is this not the case? Is there a way to have an email sent through a journey show up in the calendar?

I rarely use this feature. However, in the article you mentioned, it also states:

Not Included in the Calendar
This list displays non-searchable items that are not displayed in the Calendar.
Triggered sends
Test sends
Single sends
Pending user-initiated sends that are part of a scheduled or running program
Sends suppressed from tracking

Journey Builder is a bit different. Whenever you create an email send activity there, it also create a triggered send for that email activity.
You even can find the triggered send name and its customer key for that email activity in the Interactions tab> Triggered emails in Email Studio.
Therefore journey builder sends won't show up in the calendar IMHO.

Oh I didn't know about the Journey -> Triggered pipeline, but yeah I see that every Journey in the org has a linked Triggered send. So if the calendar doesn't show triggered sends, it makes sense that it wouldn't show the journey sends as well since they're basically repackaged triggered sends. Thank you

Yeah email activities in Journey Builder are essentially Triggered Sends.
